# Associating values in unrelated tables

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I am updating an old call datasheet that my manager decided to bring to life. The sheet tracks interval call data - queue name, calls offered, calls answered, calls abandoned, and skill name. It is an Excel document that is linked to a backend SQL database. I only have the ability to pull the data down, not alter anything on the server.

Each queue name belongs to a business unit. When the sheet was initially created in 2016 - there were five queues to each business unit. The business unit was identified by skill name. Now there are 15-20 queues to each business unit. All of the formulas in this sheet reference the skill name and not the queue name. I have been able to update the sheet to show interval call data but what I would like to do is associate the queue name with the related skill name. I am using power query for the first time ever in Excel but for the life of me, I can't figure out.

I have one table called [fact_queue] that has all of the interval call data and another called [dim_skill]. I have them set up as a cross join as they are completely unrelated. The [mart] is a placeholder for the database that I am connecting to.  What I am looking to do is have the

I have no idea how to set it up so that the proper queue name matches the proper skill name. or if it is even possible.

```
SELECT [mart].[dim_date].[date_date] as 'Date'
       ,[mart].[dim_interval].[interval_name] as 'Interval'
          ,[mart].[dim_queue].[queue_name] as 'Queue'
      ,[mart].[fact_queue].[offered_calls] as 'Calls Offered'
      ,[mart].[fact_queue].[answered_calls] as 'Calls Answered'
      ,[mart].[fact_queue].[abandoned_calls] 'Abandoned Calls'
      ,[mart].[dim_skill].[skill_name] as 'Skill'


  FROM [mart].[fact_queue]
    cross join [mart].[dim_skill]

    join [mart].[dim_queue]
    on [mart].[dim_queue].[queue_id] = [mart].[fact_queue].[queue_id]

    join [mart].[bridge_time_zone]
    on [mart].[fact_queue].[interval_id] = [mart].[bridge_time_zone].[interval_id]
    and [mart].[fact_queue].[date_id] = [mart].[bridge_time_zone].[date_id]
            
    join [mart].[dim_date]
    on [mart].[bridge_time_zone].[local_date_id] = [mart].[dim_date].[date_id]

    join [mart].[dim_interval]
    on [mart].[bridge_time_zone].[local_interval_id] = [mart].[dim_interval].[interval_id]
        
    join [mart].[dim_time_zone]
    on [mart].[dim_time_zone].[time_zone_id] = [mart].[bridge_time_zone].[time_zone_id]

        
    
where [mart].[dim_date].[date_date] between '20210228' and '20210302'
        
            
order by [mart].[dim_date].[date_date] 
      ,[mart].[dim_interval].[interval_name] 
      ,[mart].[dim_skill].[skill_name]
```

Can someone assist?

Updated to add sample data.

[image: table data]

Comment: No one can tell you how you can match *your* unrelated data between two entities. Please, include some examples and sample data. Also the query provided is not a PowerQuery syntax.Add more details on what is your exact problem.

Comment: I am not sure what power query syntax is - first time using it but it is copied from PowerQuery in Excel.  I have attached sample data.  I am looking to associate the Queue values with the Skill values.  So that when I update the formula on my other tabs (it is extensive), it will use Skill.

Comment: From your question, there is a parent-child relationship between Skill(business unit) and Queue. Assuming this relationship has been included in your data model then there will either be a Fact:Skill relationship or a Queue:Skill relationship (or possibly both) - please provide the table definitions for [fact_queue], [dim_queue] and [dim_skill] as well as some sample data for each one (that is consistent across all 3 tables). Obviously, if this relationship has not been included in your model then the model will need to be changed if you want to use it in this way